# Motion in Rotating vs. Ground frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics

Let us imagine a rotating platform moving with speed $\omega$, and let us assume that this platform is non-frictional. So if we are placing an object in the platform and looking at it from the platform  itself it will be moving radially outward due to the centrifugal force. But when the same object rotating in this platform is looked  from the ground reference frame which is  at rest, it would be still moving in the radial direction but  there is no force acting on the object in the ground frame(centrifugal force being a pseudo force depending upon frame of reference).Why is this so? How come no force act on it and still it moves in the ground frame?

Comment: Hi! Your question looks like it may be conceptual, and may be appropriate for this site. I think you would get a better response from the community if you edit your post and fix grammar, punctuation, and capitalization. As of now, it is difficult to read.

Comment: i guess now its ok to read and understand

Answer (score 0):

> let us assume that this platform is non-frictional. So if we are
> placing an object in the platform and looking at it from the platform
> itself it will be moving radially outward due to the centrifugal
> force.

This is not true. If the surface of the platform is indeed non-frictional, then an object placed on the platform will not move radially outward.
In the ground frame, it will  stay at rest where it is placed, while the platform rotates beneath it. It will be as if it were hovering above the surface of the platform because the platform cannot exert any horizontal force on it because of no friction

Imagine if you hold your finger in the air , an inch above the rotating platform. Your finger will not experience any horizontal force, right ? Similarly, if there is not enough friction then the object will not experience any horizontal force even though it is in contact with the platform

Comment: so if we were to assume there is friction which is not enough to provide the  centripetal acceleration how do we explain the radial movement of the object from ground frame there is no outward forces right

Comment: If the friction is not enough to provide the centripetal acceleration, then there will NOT BE any radial movement of the object in ground fame. In ground frame, it will just sit there as if hovering over the disc

Comment: @HARISHANKARM Imagine if you hold your finger in the air , an inch above the rotating platform. Your finger will not experience any horizontal force, right ? Similarly, if there is not enough friction then the object will not experience any horizontal force even though it is in contact with the platform